# Is ProcessBuilder aware of environment variable?

Tags: java, processbuilder

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Suppose that a java program (say, my.jar) uses ProcessBuilder to start subprocess.

If I start the program with `VAR=xxx java -jar my.jar`, will the subprocess be aware of the environment variable VAR is set to xxx?

Comment: Did you try it?  What did you discover?

Comment: My conclusion is not aware. But I want to confirm.

Comment: Maybe `export VAR=xxx` works.

Comment: This highly depends on how exactly you use ProcessBuilder. Did you take a look at ProcessBuilder's `environment()` function?

Comment: OK. This explains I don't see the env var passed from the parent process to the child processes. Are there any other things that could prevent parent env vars be seen in the child processes?

Answer (score 0):

Variables will be passed on if they are set correctly depending on your OS and command shell.

On Windows use `set VAR=xyz` or edit environment variables in Settings. For bash on GNU/Linux  `export VAR=xyz`. These variables should be passed onto java process and any sub-process called with `ProcessBuilder`.

Note that you can also change the environment settings of the sub-process by altering the  values of `environment()` before `start()`.

On GNU/Linux with `bash` a local variable declaration such as `VAR=XYZ` isn't always passed on to the java process or sub-process.  For example VAR2 here is passed to the java application but not VAR1 - but passes both values if first line is changed to `export VAR1=123`:

```
VAR1=123
VAR2=456 java -jar xyz.jar
```

Comment: OK. This explains I don't see the env var passed from the parent process to the child processes. Are there any other things that could prevent parent env vars be seen in the child processes? I would like an exhaustive list.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question with details on what you are currently doing, and what you want to see inside your java process and sub-process. If you cannot see your variable then you probably haven't exported the value, and `environment()` may be better way to control the variables in the sub-process.

Comment: The original problem stems from a large software that I cannot easily isolate the problem. Thus, I was looking at the java doc, which is just helpless in this case. That is why I want to know all the situations that prevent env var from passing on to the child processes.

Comment: Your question should tell us the OS, how you set the var, how you then call your Java app, the value of variable inside your java app, how you call the sub-process, and ideally the value of variable inside your sub-process.

Comment: Java is OS independent. So the OS does not matter. I've already mentioned how I set the var and how I call my Java app. The specific value doesn't matter, as I am asking the question generically. The sub-process is called via ProcessBuilder, are there multiple ways to call ProcessBuilder?

Comment: Setting variables is OS dependent. On GNU/Linux using `VAR=xyz java ...` passes on VAR as if it was exported.

Comment: It is shell dependent not OS dependent. On windows, you can also have bash like shell to use `VAR=xyz java`. The fact that I use `VAR=xyz java`, means it is a bash like shell.